# CSS outline solely around parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, outline

I have a div that has additional child divs attached to it with positioning outside of parent div.

I want the parent div to have an outline onclick, but the outline extends around the child divs.

Is there any way to have the outline solely around the parent div.

I cant use border as the parent div already has a border, I only want to use outline to hightlight the clicked div.

Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/PZ7eW/1

Comment: Difficult to understand  , some jsfiddle will help us..

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or codepen of what you have? Or add some pictures to show what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: add some code snippit to better understand the problem

Comment: Sorry I thought the question was self explanatory without the need for code. A div element has outline set to 1px solid black when the element is clicked. The div has an inner div with postioning set to top-50px, left-50px. this puts the child div outside the parent div. when the parent div is clicked  the outline spans not only the parent div but the inner div also. Is there a js or jquery workaround that makes the parent div to have the outline only  heres a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PZ7eW/1/

Comment: I am still missing what the wanted outcome is. In the fiddle the outline you are adding to the parent is only applied to the parent, at least in Chrome. i.e. the red border is going only around the div that says "this is the parent div" which is what I understood the wanted outcome to be.

Comment: ahh I see, that is why I dont develop in chrome as it seems to have many idiosyncrasies similar to IE. in firefox the outline is covering the parent div and the child div, so the outline is 200px by300px

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly, you need to change `border` when the `div` is active. `outline` covers the rectangle enclosing all elements in the element.

**EDIT**

Due to comments, it looks like you can't change the border nor use outer wrapper for the "outline". You can try inner positoned element instead. Please take a look at the fiddle.

Also `div` can't normally receive focus, hence it can't be blurred either. You can force any element to receive focus by setting a `tabindex` for the element.

Looks like `outline` behaves differently in different browsers: In FF it covers the rectangle enclosing all elements in the element, in Chrome and IE it covers only the parent element (which is expected behavior), in Opera `outline` occurs around every child element too. Hence the answer to the original question is: not possible to achieve this simply changing the `outline`.

[A demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s2KSt/1/).

Comment: as stated in the original question, the border is already in use

Comment: Then you'll need an extra wrapper for the `div`. Just a moment, I'll fix the answer...

Comment: I cant have an extra wrapper as this will interfere with some jquery i am running, i would post all the code but theres over 2000 lines and it seems irrelevant to the question. I was just hoping that there was some sort of quick easy workaround to the border question

Comment: There's no need for 2000 lines of code : ). The fiddle code in the question would be nice though. If you can't use a wrapper, then how about inner positioned element?

Comment: sorry I had already posted a jsfiddle above   jsfiddle.net/PZ7eW/1

Comment: ok I have updated the jsfiddle with a inner wrapper positioned outside the parent and it adds a highlighted border to the parent div. thanks for that, new added on question, why will the blur function not work? am I doing something wrong http://jsfiddle.net/PZ7eW/2/

Comment: @BarryWatts There's actually no focus gained to the `div`, so it can't be blurred. You need to add `tabindex` to get a `div` receive the focus. Like at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrrjK/).

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So I can show what I am trying to do, I have created a new jsfiddle with two matching parent divs, when you click on the first div, followed by the second div you will see what I am trying to achieve, but if you thne click on the first div again, it doesnt hide the border and child of the second div, but a click on the second div does work. Can you see why this happens http://jsfiddle.net/PZ7eW/3/

Comment: Yep, I can see multiple `id`s in the fiddle, `id`s must always be unique.

Comment: I have it working, thanks for your help http://jsfiddle.net/MrrjK/2/ I cant make yours as the right answer as the original question was about outline and it is working as a border but I will mark up with a plus 1